# Accessing unallocated page

Tags: c++, operating-system, gdb, virtual-memory

In concept of virtual memory, physical page frame is allocated only when corresponding page is used in virtual space.

**I wonder when such allocation takes place.**

I tried to reference some addresses randomly chosen, but most of the time, it gives me a segmentation fault. I guess most pages are marked non-using, and simply reading page is not enough to force OS to allocate me a physical page frame. (I tried this with GDB)

Comment: _**I wonder when such allocation takes place.**_ In an operating system call.

Comment: You must only reference memory that was allocated by your program, either as part of static or automatic storage, or as the result of a dynamic allocation function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS will handle this. To see it in action you will need to instrument or apply debugger to the OS kernel code, but the concept may be seen by:

```
int *p = new int[1000000];
```

This will allocate approximately 4MB (1000 pages) of memory, but so far NONE of them have been used, so none of it will be "physically allocated" (but perhaps the first one actually has, since it is likely used to store the metadata for the allocation)

```
p[2048] = 42;
```

Now, the OS will take a page-fault for 8192 bytes into the allocation, and once that is complete, the value 42 can be written to that page.

Running GDB will not show this. Other than the fact that it's significantly slower than writing to an already "committed" physical page, it's unnoticeable - you could try this out by writing to one element in every 4K in 100MB of data, or the first 250000 entries in the same 100MB - and then writing a second time. Both will be faster the esecond time, but thanks to the page-faults not happening the second time, the second time in the first case will be noticeably faster.

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

void measure(const std::string& test, std::function<void()> function)
{
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    function();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_time);
    std::cout<<test<<" "<<static_cast<double>(duration.count()) * 0.000001<<" ms"<<std::endl;
}

const int NWRITES = 1024*1024;
const int PAGESTEP = 1024;
const int NINTS = NWRITES*PAGESTEP; /* 1024M * sizeof(int) = 4GB */

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int [NINTS]);

    measure("Every int", [&p](){ for(int i = 0; i < NWRITES; i++) p[i] = i; });
    measure("Every 4KB", [&p](){ for(int i = 0; i < NWRITES; i++) p[i*PAGESTEP] = i; });    
    measure("Every int", [&p](){ for(int i = 0; i < NWRITES; i++) p[i] = i; });
measure("Every 4KB", [&p](){ for(int i = 0; i < NWRITES; i++) p[i*PAGESTEP] = i; });
}
```

Gives something like this:

```
Every int 10.3651 ms
Every 4KB 1856.2 ms
Every int 2.4179 ms
Every 4KB 84.1603 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

The access violations you are describing are the result of logical pages not being valid; not the fact they have not been accessed. The creation of a real page in virtual memory takes several steps of allocation.

To understand this, you need to split the concepts of logical memory translation and virtual memory.

A memory management unit presents a contiguous logical address space. Within that address space, pages may or may not map to physical page frames. While the address space may be contiguous, the range of valid pages usually is not contiguous.

The memory management unit translates logical addresses to physical addresses using a PAGE TABLE.

Processors generally use either multiple page tables or nested page tables (one table reference another that references another to identify the page frame). In the former case, the length of page table may be shorter than the full range of addresses. That can be true of the latter as well but in addition, page tables referencing nested tables (may have null entries).

This page table structure is created with the process. Having a page table ENTRY is a prerequisite for having having a mapping. On system with nested page tables, the size of the page table can be adjusted by adding entries. The size of the table is usually limited by system parameters or process quotas. (Ignoring Unix Cloning, systems with persistent shells, and system tables) At process startup, the page table entries refer to nothing.

The program loader does the initial set up of the page mapping. This sets up the page table so that the program (as defined by the LINKER) has valid addresses in the page table.

An actual page frame will not be mapped to the page until is accessed in most cases. However, you will not see that in your applications. If the page table indicates that the page is valid and you reference a page without a physical frame, that triggers a page fault. The operating system will then create the page frame mapping and restart your application. (Virtual Memory)

Your application can map additional pages at run time. New and Malloc do this behind the scenes for you but you can do it directly as well. When you create such mappings you are altering the page table so that it says the logical page is valid. You normally then have to reference the page for the operating system to map the logical page to a physical page frame.

(Assuming you are not trying to write or execute) In short, you are describing the failure of logical memory translation due to there being no valid page table entry
for the pages you are trying to access.